# Changing the ICC profile of a windows display using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, colors

Windows does a Piecewise SRGB adaption for any HDR content on windows 11. Its frustrating, it makes thing gray and cant get true blacks. You can use an ICC profile to change the curve to match gamma 2.2, but you have to do it everytime you want to use HDR and swap it back when you use SDR, because SDR is in the correct Gamma range.

I was trying to make a C++ app that would automatically switch this for me, but i've been ramming my head against a wall for awhile, messing around with several windows libraries. ICM. The [Icm.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icm/) has support for it, but it requires a ["Source ID"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icm/nf-icm-colorprofileadddisplayassociation) of a display to change that display's ICC profile. I have every other piece of code written, but I can't even figure out what a Source ID actually is. The remarks page at the end doesn't mention it, and the only other mention of a Source ID I've found so far is in the [UWP Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displaysource?view=winrt-22621). Am I missing something, or is the documentation for this header awful, or is it both? Is this even possible? Has anyone else messed with this?

The code in question I wouldn't expect to be much help, but I can post it if need be. Its very basic right now.

```
LUID adapterLUID;
//Specifies which profile to use
std::wstring profile = L"SDR ACM: srgb_d50 [ srgb_to_gamma2p2.cal ]";
PCWSTR pcwProfile = profile.c_str();
//get active display - currently only works for single monitor setups.
uint32_t sourceID = convertStringToUint32(GetSourceIDOfActiveDisplay());
//get adapterLUID
try
{
    adapterLUID = getLUID();
}
catch (const std::exception& ex)
{
    return 1;
}

HRESULT colorProfileResult = ColorProfileAddDisplayAssociation(
    WCS_PROFILE_MANAGEMENT_SCOPE_SYSTEM_WIDE,
    pcwProfile,
    adapterLUID,
    sourceID,
    true,
    true
```

The string conversion is because I thought I had found a way... but it didn't work out.

Comment: Following the link in the "Remarks" section, it then links to "The Connecting and Configuring Displays (CCD) [Win32 APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/ccd-apis)". The first function there is [DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-displayconfiggetdeviceinfo) and it uses [DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-displayconfig_device_info_header) which has a member named `id` with a type of `UINT32`. This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Possibly. I'll look into it, but i havent had time to mess with this lately. Thank you for the help.